# Converting Negative values in datagridview into parentheses

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I had this code that tries to convert negative values in a datagridview to parentheses.

For example: if cell value is "-3", the datagridview should display "(3)"

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub LoadDATAGRIDVIEWDataSUBJECTS()
    sqlCon.Open()
    Try
        Dim QUERY As String
        QUERY = "SELECT ListofSubjects.[Course No.], Curriculum.[Lab.] + Curriculum.[Lec.] " &
                "FROM StudentAcademicRecords INNER JOIN SREGStudentInformation ON StudentAcademicRecords.StudentID = SREGStudentInformation.ID INNER JOIN [Class Schedule LINE] ON StudentAcademicRecords.[Subject Code] = [Class Schedule LINE].SchedID INNER JOIN Curriculum ON [Class Schedule LINE].[Subject Code] = Curriculum.[Subject Code] INNER JOIN ListofSubjects ON Curriculum.SubjectID = ListofSubjects.SubjectID INNER JOIN CourseOfferings ON StudentAcademicRecords.Course = CourseOfferings.CourseID AND Curriculum.CourseID = CourseOfferings.CourseID INNER JOIN SchoolYear ON StudentAcademicRecords.[Academic Year] = SchoolYear.[SY ID] INNER JOIN SemesterList ON StudentAcademicRecords.Period = SemesterList.SemID AND Curriculum.SemesterID = SemesterList.SemID " &
                "WHERE (SREGStudentInformation.[Student ID] = '" & cmbStudentID.Text & "') AND (SemesterList.[Sem.] = '" & cmbSemester.Text & "') AND (SchoolYear.[School Year] = '" & cmbSchoolYear.Text & "')"

        CMD = New SqlCommand(QUERY, sqlCon)
        Reader = CMD.ExecuteReader

        DTable.Load(Reader)
        dgvSubjects.DataSource = DTable

        dgvSubjects.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Units"
        dgvSubjects.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        dgvSubjects.Columns(0).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Reader.Close()
    sqlCon.Close()
    LoadOtherInfo()

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvSubjects.Rows
        If row.Cells(1).Value < 0 Then
            row.Cells(1).Value = FormatNumber((row.Cells(1).Value), 0, UseParensForNegativeNumbers:=TriState.True)
        End If
    Next
```

But the problem is, i got this error. If you would mind to take a look at the image:
[image: Datagridview Error]

How do i fix this problem? Thanks for the help

Comment: The DGV is for presenting a **view** of the **data** in a **grid**.  Rather than looping on a bunch of rows the user may never look at or changing the data from numeric to text, use the `DefaultCellStyle` property to change the *view* presented to them

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting issues.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798703/search-a-datagridview-without-doing-an-sql-query/45802576#45802576

Comment: ...I mean if you want to manipulate data, use a datatable for this purpose and then assign the datatable as a datasource to the DGV.